# Custom Twig Tags

Tags: templating, tags

I'm working on a site with a very complex permissions structure (based on groups, dates, dynamic overrides etc). I've written a custom permissions plugin to handle this in a centralized fashion.

In this plugin I've exposed some of the functionality through twig variables:

```
{{ craft.permissions.require('update','entry.projects', project.id) }}
```

This function is similar to the {% requireLogin %} where it performs redirects and stops craft processing etc if it fails the permissions check.

I need to somehow execute this as a twig tag so that I can place it outside the {% block content %} tags.

Is there a way to create custom twig tags?

---

Alternatively; 
as a work around I'm using the 'if' tag which is a bit messy:

```
{% if craft.permissions.require('update','entry.projects', project.id) %}{% endif %}
```

A different tag dedicated to running functions could be useful in the next release, eg:

```
{% exec craft.permissions.require('update','entry.projects', project.id) %}
```

Comment: You may also want to look at Twig's [`do` tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/do.html)... It basically just executes a statement without returning anything.

Comment: awesome thanks mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to create custom twig tags?

Sure.  You can look in `craft/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/` to see how Craft creates it's own [custom Twig tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tags), which is how a plugin would do it using the [addTwigExtension](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#addTwigExtension) hook.